# How to set up a gorilla/websocket connection to acts as JSON-RPC client for browsers applications?

Tags: go, websocket, rpc, json-rpc, gorilla

I have a frontend [aplication](https://gist.github.com/fpawel/6953dfafef1591300c62e1a1ea1db97c), that connects to websocket and try to serve  json-rpc2 to call client side from server. What is the best way to create `*rpc.Client` for it in a server application written in Go with "github.com/gorilla/websocket"? I tried to use `UnderlyingConn()` of `*websocket.Conn`: `jsonrpc2.NewClient(conn.UnderlyingConn())`, but it does not work.

Comment: It is possible and I already made such a client. But I would like to avoid the boilerplate associated with the manual implementation of the protocol, which is perfectly implemented in the standard library, and use `*rpc.Client` instead.

Comment: А good suggestion, thank you.

Comment: @ThunderCat, maybe do you mean [ClientCodec](https://godoc.org/net/rpc#ClientCodec)?

Comment: What about [that](https://gist.github.com/fpawel/ba3738ed6309d917530de4342c12ce4a)? Does this seem acceptable? I used protected ReadJSON / WriteJSON .

Answer (score 3):

I provide [NewClient](https://godoc.org/github.com/powerman/rpc-codec/jsonrpc2#NewClient) with [io.ReadWriteCloser](https://godoc.org/io#ReadWriteCloser) implementation which convert read/writes to [websocket](https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/websocket#Conn) operations, thanks to [powerman](https://github.com/powerman).

```
package jsonrpc2ws

import (
    "github.com/powerman/rpc-codec/jsonrpc2"
    "github.com/gorilla/websocket"
    "encoding/json"
    "io"
    "sync"
)

func NewClient(ws *websocket.Conn) *jsonrpc2.Client {
    c := &client{
        ws:ws,
    }
    c.initRead()
    c.initWrite()
    return jsonrpc2.NewClient(c)
}

type client struct {
    w *io.PipeWriter
    r *io.PipeReader
    ws *websocket.Conn

    err error      // io error
    mu sync.Mutex  // protects err
}


func (x *client) error() (err error) {
    x.mu.Lock()
    err = x.err
    x.mu.Unlock()
    return
}

func (x *client) setError (err error) {
    x.mu.Lock()
    if x.err != nil {
        x.err = err
    }
    x.mu.Unlock()
}

func (x *client) initRead(){
    var w *io.PipeWriter
    x.r, w = io.Pipe()
    go func(){
        _,b,err := x.ws.ReadMessage()
        for  ; x.error() == nil && err == nil; _,b,err = x.ws.ReadMessage(){
            _,err = w.Write(b)
        }
        x.setError(err)
        w.Close()
    } ()
}

func (x *client) initWrite(){
    var r *io.PipeReader
    r,x.w = io.Pipe()
    go func(){
        dec := json.NewDecoder(r)
        var b json.RawMessage
        err := dec.Decode(&b)
        for  ; x.error() == nil &&  err == nil; err = dec.Decode(&b){
            err = x.ws.WriteMessage(websocket.TextMessage, b)
        }
        x.setError(err)
        r.Close()
    } ()
}

func (x *client) Write(p []byte) (int, error){
    if x.error() != nil {
        return 0, x.error()
    }
    return x.w.Write(p)
}

func (x *client) Read(p []byte) (int, error){
    if x.error() != nil {
        return 0, x.error()
    }
    return x.r.Read(p)
}

func (x *client) Close() error{
    x.ws.Close()
    x.w.Close()
    x.r.Close()
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the `nhooyr.io/websocket` package's `Net.Conn` wrapper.

https://pkg.go.dev/nhooyr.io/websocket#NetConn

> It's for tunneling arbitrary protocols over WebSockets. Few users of the library will need this but it's tricky to implement correctly and so provided in the library. See https://github.com/nhooyr/websocket/issues/100.

The linked issue contains more details.

The [golang x/net/websocket package](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/net/websocket) lacks a lot of features. Sadly
[the gorilla toolkit](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket) has been
archived and is not maintained.

The `nhooyr/websocket` package worked for me though, and is actually [recommended by the golang package](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/net/websocket#pkg-overview)